# Wikidata reconciliation with OpenRefine—get only those subjects with English as the language flag

Tags: wikidata, sparql, openrefine

*Leptospermum scoparium* ([Q1520028](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1520028)) has [8 common name (P1843) entries](https://w.wiki/433L).

I have data in OpenRefine reconciled to this object:
[image: Google OpenRefine screenshot showing plain-text data reconciled to WikiData]

How can I get only those [P1843](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1843) entries that are in English? The [reconciliation documentation](https://wikidata.reconci.link) says to use `Len` to get, for example, the English label of a given object, but I can't work out the SPARQL syntax that would deliver what I want.

I have tried `P1843/Len` and `P1843|Len` but these operators don't work the way I thought:

[image: OpenRefine reconcile data modal]

I realise I can limit the number of values returned per row, but the values are returned in the order in which they appear, meaning in this instance the Welsh common name appears first.

If I can't do what I need through a SPARQL-like syntax on the reconcile screen, is there some way to obtain the JSON response from the reconciliation and parse it? I've tried [`jsonize(cell.recon.match)`](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#format-based-functions-json-html-xml) but that just gives:

```
{"id":"Q1520028","name":"Leptospermum scoparium","types":["Q16521"],"score":100}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do this simply via the reconciliation API. What you could do instead is use the "Add columns by fetching URLs" feature to retrieve the JSON representation of the item from Wikidata (for instance with the expression `"https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/"+cell.recon.match.id+".json"`).

Then manipulate that object to get what you need (probably doable in GREL, but personally I would go for Python).

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That syntax is exactly the sort of thing I wanted -- how to build my own query and parse the JSON.